# I can't install pip for python 3.5

Tags: python, pip

My friend owns a Raspberry Pi, and no matter what we try to do we cannot get pip3 installed for python 3.5. We've tried `get-pip.py`, but that only works for 2.7. We've tried `sudo pip install -U pip`, but that only upgrades pip2.7. We've tried `sudo apt-get install python3.5-pip`, but the package doesn't exist. We've tried `sudo easy_install3 pip` too. I can't figure out how in the world to do this.

(`pip3` works, but that's for `/usr/bin/python3`, not `/usr/local/bin/python3.5`.)

Help?

Comment: It seems this could help: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/54365/how-to-download-and-install-python-3-5-in-raspbian/56632#56632

Answer (score 0):

You were actually very close:

`$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip`

When you say that `pip3` works then I'm pretty sure that is the `pip` for the latest version of Python3. Can you do `pip3 --version`?

This should help too: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/software/python.md

Comment: I can't use python 3. I need python 3.5. And no I can't troubleshoot this because I don't have access to his Pi.

Comment: If you install python3-pip, you get the newest python version availble in the package manager. That might be 3.5 or some other version. If it is not 3.5, then its not available using your package manager.